# Database-->graph

Tags: php, javascript, database, graph

I currently have a database with column A and column B. I want to get the data and put an edge from A to B. I have no problem with that. The problem is, many A can refer to 1 B and I dont want to have duplicates A's in my graph. How can solve my following problem?

I am using PHP +js.

Comment: This is highly db-specific. What database do you use? SQL or graph? In either case, there are lots of good jQuery libs for drawing out the data. There are also PHP-libs for generating pictures with graphs. Other than that it's hard to say what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very confusing the way you worded it.  What do you mean by "put an edge from A to B?"  As for not having duplicate A's, do you mean you don't want duplicate A rows entering your database in the first place?  Do you mean you want to have duplicate A's in the database but you only want one of them to show up in the graph?  Color me thoroughly confused.  Perhaps a live example would help us figure out what you'd like help with?

Comment: Sorry, here is an example:
shirt --> pants
bag --> pants
shoes--> socks

here, both shirt and bag refer to pants. I do not want to have 2 separate nodes for pants. There should be 2 nodes (bag and shirt) that have a directed edge to a single node pants. I hope my example cleared the confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

a very late reply, but still. normally, one would do that with pointers. php does not have pointers, but has something called pass by reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

an example would look like this:

```
$shirt = new Node('shirt');
$pants = new Node('pants');
$bag = new Node('bag');

$shirt->relate_to($panths);
$bag->relate_to($panths);

class Node {
  protected $type;
  protected $relations;

  public function relate_to(Node &$node) {
    $this->relations[$node->id] = &$node;
  }
}
```

it is even possible to make a directed relations like this:

```
  public function relate(node &$from, node &$to){
            $tmp=new relationship($from, $to);
            $from->relations[$to->id]=&$tmp;
            $to->relations[$from->id]=&$tmp;
    }
```